# How can I make hoptoad in Django 1.2 log errors to log file as well as send airbrake notifications?

Tags: django, hoptoad

We're using django 1.2.7 and the hoptoad logging middleware (hoptoad.middleware.HoptoadNotifierMiddleware).

When an error occurs, the error message gets sent to airbrake, but it does not seem to get logged to the django log file. It seems like it's intercepted by hoptoad exclusively.

Does anyone know how to also get the errors logged to the local django log file on disk? I couldn't find any such option in the hoptoad documentation.

Is there a custom modification needed to the hoptoad middleware class?